# Is it expected that Node apps will stop working as newer versions of their dependencies are created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to follow a tutorial online for some web development topics, which has associated code on github.  When I download it, the associated directory structure looks like this:

```
E:\dev\angular-components-step-1>dir

 Directory of E:\dev\angular-components-step-1

09/18/2021  10:53 PM    <DIR>          .
09/18/2021  10:53 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/18/2021  10:52 PM                44 .gitignore
09/18/2021  10:53 PM    <DIR>          client
09/18/2021  10:52 PM             1,504 Gulpfile.js
09/18/2021  10:52 PM               824 package.json
09/18/2021  10:52 PM               245 README.md
09/18/2021  10:52 PM               516 webpack.config.js
               5 File(s)          3,133 bytes
```

The person who created the tutorial I'm following said to run `npm install` after downloading it.  When I did so, I got the following:

```
E:\dev\angular-components-step-1>npm install
npm WARN deprecated angular-ui-router@0.2.18: This npm package 'angular-ui-router' has been renamed to '@uirouter/angularjs'. Please update your package.json. See https://ui-router.github.io/blog/uirouter-scoped-packages/
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated lodash.padright@3.1.3: This package is discontinued. Use lodash.padend@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated css-list@0.1.3: Deprecated.
npm WARN deprecated postcss-single-charset@0.3.0: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@0.4.0: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated flatten@0.0.1: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ng-blog@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

It looks to me like the problem is that newer versions of the packages used in this app have come out since this tutorial was created.

My questions are:

1. Even if newer versions of these packages have been released, why can't I just use the versions specified in the project.json?
2. What is the general process I need to follow if I want to get this working?  That is, can I just get the current versions and everything should work, or is there something I need to do to ensure that everything works together?
3. Is it generally expected that things like this will happen with projects downloaded from github if they were created a while ago, and it's just something that often needs to be dealt with?

Comment: Also there are a lot of current packages that rely on deprecated packages and at some point they will either need to upgrade or not depending on what that dependency does and what if any issues it has. Most of these are questions for the package maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Updates never affect previous versions, only newer ones. So, so long as it did work on the tutorial you're following, it should work for you too. Notice, however, that the caret and tilde operators in `package.json` [download the latest minor or patch version, accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json). So there's a chance you will use slightly more updated versions than the tutorial. Either way, usually it shouldn't cause problems.